# How do I solve "template argument deduction/substitution failure" when implementing multi-type arithmetic operators

Tags: c++, c++17

I can't seem to find the correct way to implement it, this seems to be the closest to the right way but I am getting a template argument deduction error. Can anyone point out where I went wrong?

I am trying to add arithmetic capabilities to `std::variant` without needing to `std::get` first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template<typename... Types>
class variant : public std::variant<Types...> {
    private:
      template <class Op, typename T, int index = 0>
      decltype(auto) calc(const T& other) const {
        if(sizeof...(Types) == 0 || index >= sizeof...(Types)){
          return;
        }

        using ST = std::variant_alternative_t<index, std::variant<Types...>>;

        if(std::holds_alternative<ST>(
          std::variant<Types...>(*this)
        )){
          if(std::is_same<T, variant<Types...>>::value){
            return Op()(std::get<ST>(*this), std::get<ST>(other));
          }
          else{
            return Op()(std::get<ST>(*this), other);
          }
        }

        return this->calc<Op, index+1>(other);
      }

    public:
      using std::variant<Types...>::variant;

      template <typename T>
      decltype(auto) operator-(const T& other) const {
        return this->calc<std::minus>(other);
      }

      // other operations will be added; std::plus, etc.
};

int main()
{
    variant<int, double> vt1 = 2.3;
    variant<int, double> vt2 = 5;

    std::cout << "first: " << (vt1 - 2) << std::endl; 

    std::cout << "second: " << (vt2 - vt1) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

1. `std::minus` is not a type, but a template. It cannot bind to `class Op`. You might want to use `std::minus<>` instead.
2. When you call `calc<Op, index + 1>()` from `calc<Op, index>()` you get infinite recursion. The `if` condition at the beginning does not help, because a compiler still has to generate that call: this condition is checked at the run-time, not at the compile-time. You need `if constexpr`.
3. Inconsistent types for `decltype(auto)` return type. All non-discarded branches should return the same type.
4. `Op()(std::get<ST>(*this), std::get<ST>(other))` will throw if `*this` and `other` hold different types (and in your example they do hold different types).

Instead of fixing all these and reinventing `std::visit`, you can simply define free functions and use `std::visit` in the implementation:

```
namespace impl {
    template<class T>
    auto get_value(const T& t) {
        return t;
    }

    template<class... Ts>
    auto get_value(const std::variant<Ts...>& var) {
        using T = std::common_type_t<Ts...>;
        return std::visit([](T value) { return value; }, var);
    }

    template<class Op, class T, class U>
    auto var_op(Op op, const T& t, const U& u) {
        return op(get_value(t), get_value(u));
    }
}

template<class... Ts, class U>
auto operator-(const std::variant<Ts...>& var, const U& u) {
    return impl::var_op(std::minus<>{}, var, u);
}

template<class U, class... Ts>
auto operator-(const U& u, const std::variant<Ts...>& var) {
    return impl::var_op(std::minus<>{}, u, var);
}

template<class... Ts, class... Us>
auto operator-(const std::variant<Ts...>& var1, 
               const std::variant<Us...>& var2) {
    return impl::var_op(std::minus<>{}, var1, var2);
}
```

If you want to limit these functions to your own class `my_variant` derived from `std::variant`, you need to fix `get_value()` by adding `static_cast`, because `std::visit` uses some helper classes (like `std::variant_size`) that are not specialized for `my_variant`:

```
template<class... Ts>
class my_variant : public std::variant<Ts...> {
public:
    using std::variant<Ts...>::variant;
};

...

namespace impl {
    template<class... Ts>
    auto get_value(const my_variant<Ts...>& var) {
        using T = std::common_type_t<Ts...>;
        return std::visit([](T value) { return value; }, 
            static_cast<const std::variant<Ts...>&>(var));
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding the types being different, what if its a case where I have `operator-(const CustT& v1, const int& v2)` implemented that subtracts `v2` from each in a vector in `v1`? I would then need a replacement for the `common_type_t` section.

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno, which alternative a variant holds is a run-time property, not a compile-time one. You should have a common type here or there, but details may vary. Could you please give a more detailed example?

Comment: for example, if I have a class `Point` that when paired with an integer value in a minus operation it subtracts that value from all 3 axis of the `Point`.. I would also want this to work if `Point` is in a `variant`

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno, and which types a variant should contain besides `Point`?

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno, see [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/nuFHYD).

Comment: as an example I will go with `std::variant<Point, int>`

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno, and what type should `operator-` return? The problem is that the variant's alternative is known only at the run-time, but the type should be known at the compile-time.

Comment: I would love for it to return either `Point` or `int` depending on if the variant currently holds a Point and the RHS is a `Point` or `int` since `Point - Point` which returns `Point` is also implemented

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno, C++ is a statically typed language: the return type cannot depend on a run-time quantity. At the compile time you don't know whether a variant holds `Point` or `int`. A compiler has to generate code for all possibilities. With some abusing of notations, for `variant<A, B> - C` you can return `variant<A - C, B - C>`. For `variant<A, B> - variant<C, D>` the problem is more complicated. You can return `variant<A - C, A - D, B - C, B - D>` if all these operations are defined. It can be coded, but it smells of a bad design. It result in a variant with `N^2` types.